# Execution of SetCommandTimeout not working with EF Core 5 for PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a problem when I SetCommandTimeout is like the method is not working properly.

I Use PostgreSQL as database, and for the EntityFramework Core I'm using `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` with Version `5.0.5.1`

In the code I Set Timeout for 1s like this `context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(1);` and I set a Stopwatch to check how much time it takes, but the ElapsedMiliseconds always return around 15000ms to 16000ms. so the `SetCommandTimeout(1)` is clearly not working.

I also tried using `context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` is not working either.

One more thing, I only want to Set Timeout for specific Request. So the other Request will have the default timeout.

Here's my code:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext context;

    public TestController(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(1);
            var test = await context.Test.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Stop();
            var elapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; // always return around 15000ms to 16000ms
        }
    }
}
```

here's how I register it in Startup.Cs

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(ConnectionString);
});
```

did I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command timeout is the time a query / command is allowed to execute on the database server. The timer starts when the database server receives the request. Your end-to-end round trip time may be higher than the command timeout due to network throughput or other constraints - including resource exhaustion on your web server.

> Command Timeout: The time to wait (in seconds) while trying to execute a command before terminating the attempt and generating an error.
> [Source](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html)

Comment: if this is the case, is there a way to set timeout for connecting to database server?

Comment: @JohnSari - Yes, this is the connection timeout property. You would add "Timeout=5;" to your connection string for 5 seconds.

Comment: This one works! but is there a way to set this timeout just for specific request?

Comment: How would that work? The connection timeout (`Timeout` parameter in the connection string) only manages the tmiout on establishing a physical connection; after that, the timeout for executing commands is the CommandTimeout.

Comment: @JohnSari - This particular request shouldn't take longer to get a connection than any other request to the database. If it is, your database server may be underpowered. Can you share a little more about what it's doing?

Answer (score 2):

Googled a little and found issues related to this library.

---

Based on this [forum post](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/setcommandtimeout/3063/4), it seems that the issue is coming from the source code and the settings is just being ignored.

Try to **set-up command timeout inside the creating of DB context** instead right before usage.

---

Another one is at the [github repository](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1624).

Solution for this one is to **upgrade to latest version of drivers**.

---

Another from [github](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/956).

The workaround for this is to **modify connection string during creation of context**:

```
if (!connectionString.Contains("CommandTimeout"))
{
    connectionString += $";CommandTimeout=120";
}
```

---

**EDIT (after OP mentioned he wants to use it on single request):** I would recommend by going the way with creating other database context and modifying its connection string (as above). That way you would be able to execute short/long running commands. However, this brings other issues related to the multiple DB-context and possible mismatch of data. Needs to be handled with caution.

Comment: sorry I didn't specify, I only want to Set Timeout for this Request, for another Request I don't want to set timeout. I'll edit the description for my question